# How to speed up INNER JOIN MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join, query-optimization

I'm having performance issues pulling data from 2 sql tables. It is very very slow. When I remove the INNER JOIN the page loads instantly.

```
$query = "SELECT sc.*, dr.fullName, dr.email, dr.mobile, dr.address1, dr.town, dr.postCode, dr.utr, dr.vatNo, dr.driver_number, dr.pt, dr.siteLoc, dr.vatCharge, dr.vraRate, dr.third_party_provider
FROM scheduling sc
INNER JOIN driverReg dr ON dr.ni = sc.ni
WHERE sc.ref = '".$ref."' AND sc.excluded = 'No'";
```

Does anyone have a better method of pulling this data faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

be sure you have a composite index on  table  scheduling    column (ref,  excluded,ni )

and an  index  on table driverReg    column ni

```
 create index  myidx1 on scheduling (ref,  excluded,ni )
 create index  myidx2 on driverReg (ni )
```

anyway  not related  to performance but for security  .. you should avoid the use of php in sql code because you are at risk for sqlijection  .. for avoid this you shuold take a look at your mysql driver for prepared statement and binding param

Comment: Nice. This fixed the issue. Thanks! I will accept the answer in 5 minutes.